# Trouble in eclipse: java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, android, eclipse, classcastexception, java.lang.class

it's been two days that I constantly get an error dialog box every 45 seconds with the title of :

> Multiple problems have occurred

and under it says:

> java.lang.ClassCastException

and  in the details there is a repeated line which says:

> org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode cannot be cast to org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataTreeNode

here is a picture of it:

[image]

I press OK, and continue coding, my code works fine, in both simulator and my mobile, but it's really annoying to see this dialog every minute, or my be even less than a minute!

Comment: Maybe your workspace is somehow corrupted. Try to setup a new workspace.

Comment: @user714965 Yes, you are right, i hade done something in workspace, how to setup a new workspace?

Comment: `File` -> `Switch Workspace` -> `Other` from the eclipse menu. Then choose a new directory. You will have to re-import your sources and make all configurations.

Comment: @user714965 Thanks you very much! it is fine just now! :)

Comment: @user714965 It's too old, but would you please submit your comment as an Answer so I can approve answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your workspace is somehow corrupted. Try to setup a new workspace.

Choose `File` -> `Switch Workspace` -> `Other` from the eclipse menu. Then choose a new directory. You will have to re-import your sources and make all configurations.